# Measure on $\omega$ defined in the generic extension by an atomless measure algebra is atomless

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Work in Cantor space with standard probability measure $m$. Suppose we are given a sequence of measurable sets $\bar{A}=\langle A_n : n\in \omega\rangle$ and a non-principal ultrafilter $U$ and the following is true $$\inf_{C \text{ measurable not null}} \mu_C(\bar{A})\geq r >0$$ where for a measurable set $C$, $\mu_C(\bar{A})=\lim_{n\rightarrow U} \frac{m(C\cap A_n)}{m(C)}$. For a sequence of real numbers $a_n$, the ultralimit with respect to $U$ is defined as the unique $r$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists X\in U \forall n\in X |a_n-r|<\epsilon$. My question is whether it is possible to find two sequences $\langle B_n :n\in \omega\rangle, \langle C_n: n\in \omega\rangle$ such that $B_n, C_n \subset A_n$ and $D$ measurable such that 
$$\inf_{E\subset D} \mu_E(\bar{B}) >0, \inf_{E\subset D} \mu_E(\bar{C}) >0?$$

If no infemum is taken then it is easy, say fix $E$ measurable not null, we only need to go to a large set $X\in U$ such that $\forall n\in X m(E\cap A_n)>\frac{r}{2}m(E)$. Split $A_n$ into two sets of roughly same measure, then we are done. The problem is how to make it work uniformly for each smaller neighbourhood.

The motivation from forcing in set theory [define a finitely additive measure after forcing with an atomless measure algebra, and show the new measure in the generic extension is atomless too. Used in Kunen's proof that consistently Ramsey ultrafilters do not exist]. We might also assume the ultrafilter given is Ramsey/selective though I'm not sure how helpful it would be. Thanks.

Comment: For each clopen $C \subseteq 2^{\omega}$, choose $X_C \in U$ such that for each $n \in X_C$, the fractional measure of $A_n$ in $C$ is more than $r/2$. Since $U$ is Ramsey, you can choose some $X \in U$ that is almost contained in every $X_C$. Now inductively choose $B_n, C_n$, disjoint subsets of $A_n$, such that they have $> r/4$ fractional measure in every clopen set for all sufficiently large $n \in X$. This should work because the clopen sets are dense in the measure algebra on $2^{\omega}$.

Comment: Nice! I guess I overlooked the use of Ramseyness. Also the argument still works if $U$ is merely a P-point. If it is not as nice I doubt though.

Comment: @hot_queen: wait why clopen sets are dense in measure algebra on $2^\omega$?

Comment: This is regularity: Given $e >o$, $B \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ Borel, first get an open set $U \supseteq B$ with $\mu(U \setminus B) < e/2$. Then pick a clopen set $C \subseteq U$ with $\mu(U \setminus C) < e/2$.

Comment: ok so that's what you meant, mod $\epsilon$-density I guess. Full density for clopen sets is obviously not right here. Just want to clarify.

Comment: so when the measure algebra has uncountable clopen sets, it seems like a problem? as in general the posets are like $\mathbb{MB}(2^\kappa)$

Comment: I assumed that your measure space was $2^{\omega}$. Are you now asking the same question for all $2^{\kappa}$?

Comment: Indeed. That was where the problem was from. Sorry I said Cantor space so you definitely interpreted the question the way it's supposed to be interpreted :-)

Comment: I think the same proof will work by noticing that the union of supports of the member of the sequence $\langle A_n : n < \omega \rangle$ is a countable subset $I$ of $\kappa$. So it would be enough to consider only those clopen subsets of $2^{\kappa}$ which are supported in $I$.

Comment: cool. thanks. I think it works.